# php download remote dynamic file to local server

Tags: php, file

When I make a server side call to remote http://aa.com/generatefeed.php

It should download the feed_randomnumber.csv (random file name) in real time and save it as same name, into local server.

But it doesn't work.

what's wrong.

getfeed.php

```
getremotetofile("http://aa.com/generatefeed.php");


public static function getremotetofile($fileurl)
{
    $newfilename= basename($fileurl);

    $destination=fopen($newfilename,"w");

    $source=fopen($fileurl,"r");
    $maxsize=3000;
    $length=0;
    while (($a=fread($source,1024))&&($length<$maxsize))
    {
        $length=$length+1024;
        fwrite($destination,$a);
    }
    fclose($source);
    fclose($destination);       

}
```

generatefeed.php

```
$fullcontent="bla,bla,bla";

header("Content-type:text/octect-stream");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=feed_randomnumber.csv");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($strHeader));        

print $fullcontent;

exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using CURL instead of fopen, it might be disabled on your server.

`$file = "http://somelocation.com/somefile.php";`
`$ch = curl_init($file);`
`$fp = @fopen("temp.php", "w");`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);`
`curl_exec($ch);`
`curl_close($ch);`
`fclose($fp);`
`$file = "temp.php";`
`$fp = fopen($file, "r");`

Comment: this method do work, but the csv file that duplicate over, only got 1 header line, all other lines fail to capture

Answer (score 0):

Define what doesn't work with your code. Have you enabled allow_url_fopen in your php configuration? Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   getremotetofile("http://aa.com/generatefeed.php");


    public static function getremotetofile($fileurl)
    {
      $newfilename= basename($fileurl);
        $content = file_get_contents($fileurl);
        file_put_contents($newfilename, $content);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents('localFile.csv', file_get_contents('http://www.somewhere.com/function.php?action=createCSVfile'));
```

I use this to download a remote csv created dynamically and save it on local server.